# Querying multiple tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I use MySQL and trying to write a PHP script for my school project.

There is one table named lessons contains this columns:

```
-id
-lessonid.
-studentid
```

I also have two different tables for notes and announcements
announcements and notes tables contains these columns:

```
-id
-lessonid
-content
-createdtime
```

I need to order both announcements and notes from latest to oldest by createdtime but also need to show all lessons a student takes.

For example: A students takes maths and physics lessons. I need to display him/her both notes and announcements for both of physics and maths and all items should be ordered by date. (like a timeline.) And of course I will not show him/her the notes and announcements for chemistry lesson. Also it will be good if I can say it is note or announcement on the list.

Can you help me to write SQL and PHP code for that?
Thanks.

EDIT: This is where I have stuck:
I have combined two tables and ordered them by date. But can't combine them with the lessons a student take.

```
SELECT title, created, lessonid FROM (SELECT title, created, lessonid FROM notes UNION SELECT title, created, lessonid FROM announcements) as a ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: Good luck, the wolves are coming.

Comment: you should show what you've tried, and we can help you from there

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for letting us know that this is for a school project - therefore I won't give you the answer. If it is in the project then your teacher should have given you the concepts to come up with a solution.

Your question is well put together and I can see how to solve it but ... It's your project so you need to have a crack at it and post what you come up with.

I will give you some hints to get you started.

You need a query to combine the announcements and notes table. Then you need to group the data by the lesson and join that to the students. This is all basic SQL.

Good luck. Post what you come up with.

Comment: Thanks. This is where I've stuck. I have combined two tables and ordered them by date. But can't combine them with the lessons a student take.
SELECT title, created, lessonid FROM (SELECT title, created, lessonid FROM notes UNION SELECT title, created, lessonid FROM announcements) as a ORDER BY created DESC

Comment: Look through your notes/textbook/google for the command `INNER JOIN`

Comment: i think it is not its school project but the he is making a project for a school... tell him the solution man @Dale

Answer (score 0):

I'll also, follow fellow posters advice, and not do the legwork for you. but won't let you go empty handed, so will give you the concept. 
there is a thing called third normal form, we decide how many tables according to that concept, so if its a big database then separate table for first name and separate for last name, as many people share those among themselves, so saves space and redundancy etc. so one table for person has personid as primary, and has lastname foreign key to refer to last name table , we generally name it lastNameRef, similarly firstNameRef. so now, each person has lot of classes, and each class has lot of persons(students) in it. so this is a many-many relation - we create a allreference table to solve this many to many problem. so there is one table for classes which has class id as primary key, so now u create a all reference table which a recordId as primarykey, (just for namesake) and personRef(refers to personId in person table) and classref(refers to classId in class table) if one person has two classes, another entry with same personId but different class Id, at the end, you can query the name of person from person table, and name of class from class table and create join on their foreign keys but use all three tables, result is (JOHN MATH, JOHN SCIENCE) etc, same way you display all notes for john searching name in person table, and subject in class table,and notes in notes table